# How to call a function from another component using click event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to call a function of another component which has no relation on the click

**servive File**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ShareDetailsService {
  clicked : boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

}
```

**component 2**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component2',
  templateUrl: './component2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css']
})
export class Component2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(shareDetailsService : ShareDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(shareDetailsService.clicked){
      console.log("clicked");
    }
  }
```

**Component 1**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component1',
  templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component1.component.css']
})
export class Component1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(shareDetailsService : ShareDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(shareDetailsService.clicked){
      console.log("clicked");
    }
  }
  someFunction(){
  }
```

**Component 1 Html**

```
<div (click)="someFunction()"></div>
```

When I call the function using the click event it should call the function of the another component , I created a service file and where I am able to change the boolean variable.

I Want to call the function when there is a change in the boolean Variable rather than calling the function on ngOnit()

Comment: You should add a Subject in your service and subscribe to it in the target component.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subject to subscribe to it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs' 
@Injectable()
export class ShareDetailsService {
  clicked$ = new Subject();    
}
```

// Any component can post and subscribe to it

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component2',
  templateUrl: './component2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css']
})
export class Component2Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(shareDetailsService : ShareDetailsService) {
    this.sharedDetailsService.clicked$.subscribe(() => console.log('clicked')
  }

  onClick() {
     this.sharedDetailsService.clicked$.next(); // dispatch the click
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please define this solution on stackblitz ?
I am getting confused

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e6xe1q

Comment: How to call the function from another component with this subject, I guess here in the above solution we have only one component , on click event I want to call the function of another component

Comment: It's a pub/sub pattern. You push an event in the subject (with `next()`) and every subscriber will get a notification (in `subscribe`) .